# Why do we call this theorem in vector valued functions "mean value theorem"?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definition, motivation

I didn't understand why we call this theorem below mean value theorem. I didn't understand the relationship with the mean value theorem we learn in the first semester Calculus.

> *Mean value for vector valued functions*: Let $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb R^n$ a continuous function, differentiable in the open interval $(a,b)$. If
>   $|f'(t)|\le M$ for every $t\in (a,b)$, then $|f(b)-f(a)|\le M(b-a)$.

Comment: I know it as mean value inequality, and it is an extension of the mean value theorem, for real valued functions, in which equality holds.

Comment: See [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_value_theorem#Mean_value_theorem_for_vector-valued_functions).

Comment: "[One of the miseries of life is that everybody names things a little bit wrong, and so it makes everything a little harder to understand.](https://youtu.be/EKWGGDXe5MA?t=296)" -- Richard Feynman

Answer (score 1):

In one-variable calculus, you get an equality
$$f(b)-f(a)=f'(c)(b-a)$$
for some $c\in [a,b]$. Taking absolute values, this gives
$$|f(b)-f(a)|=|f'(c)|(b-a)\leq M(b-a).$$

This means that the inequality $|f(b)-f(a)|\leq M(b-a)$ can be thought of as a weak version of the standard mean value theorem. A stronger theorem doesn't hold in general, so we give this name to the above inequality.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way of seeing why the mean value moniker applies:

One can show that if $x$ is such that $|h^Tx| \le M \|h\|$ for
all $h$, then $\|x\| \le M$.

Now pick some $h$, then note that $\phi_h(t) = h^T f(t)$ satisfies
$h^T(f(b)-f(a) ) = \phi_h(b) -\phi_h(a) = \phi'_h(\xi) (b-a) = h^T f'(\xi) (b-a)$ for some $\xi$. This is where the usual mean value theorem is used.
If we have $\|f'(t)\| \le M$, then the above becomes
$|h^T(f(b)-f(a))| \le M \|h\|\|b-a\|$ and since this is true for all $h$
we have
$\|f(b)-f(a)\| \le M \|b-a\|$.